# How to close a multiprocessing connection listener?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, connection, listener

I need help in multiprocessing. I am very new and I am mostly just trying stuff out. So I have this listener that is listening for input. I want to close the program gracefully on shutdown but since the program is stuck at listener.accept(), I can't do anything.

```
listener = multiprocessing.connection.Listener(('localhost', 6000))

def exit_gracefully():
    print("test")
    listener.close()
    # Do cleanup and exit

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, exit_gracefully)

while True:
    conn = listener.accept()
    # Do stuff.
```

I sent sigterm to the process but i never see "test" being printed out. Help me out here please.

Comment: I tested the program on a UNIX system and it does print out `test` (after editing `exit_gracefully` to take 2 arguments). Which operating system are you on?

Comment: For the question implied by the title, see [sockets - Proper way of cancelling accept and closing a Python processing/multiprocessing Listener connection - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357656/proper-way-of-cancelling-accept-and-closing-a-python-processing-multiprocessing)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should have posted a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), meaning that I should be able to copy, paste and run your code with nothing further required to reproduce your problem. But you are clearly missing required `import` statements. I make a point of telling this to you as a first-time poster for your future posts.

Class `multiprocessing.connection.Listener` is used by various classes. The problem is that you have created a listener on a port on which nobody is talking! You should register a function to be called when Python exits using `atexit.register` to handle termination for any reason. Handling `SIGTERM` requires that a Unix/Linux `kill` command be sent to the process.

```Python
import atexit
import signal
import time
import sys

def exit_gracefully():
    print("test")

def ctrl_c_hit(*args, **kwargs):
    print('CTRL-c hit!')
    sys.exit(0)

atexit.register(exit_gracefully)

# intercept CTRl-c
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, ctrl_c_hit)

print('Enter CTRL-c to terminate ...')
while True:
    time.sleep(1_000_000)
```

If you enter `CTRL-C`, you will see:

```
Enter CTRL-c to terminate ...
CTRL-c hit!
test
```

Comment: Did this not answer your question satisfactorily?